# How to append two pandas.DataFrame with different numbers of columns

Tags: python, dataframe

Based on the fact that directly append two `dataframe` with different numbers of columns, an error would occur as `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 242, saw 5`. How can I do with `pandas` to avoid the error??

I have figure out one naive approach: just to process the original data, to make the numbers of columns equally.

Can it be more elegant?? I think the missing columns can be filled with `np.nan` after `pd.append`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to concat the dataframes as shown.

You will need to rename the columns to suit you needs.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,2,3,4]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2])

print('df1')
print(df1)
print('\ndf2')
print(df2)
print('\ndf')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df1
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4

df2
   a  c
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4

df
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  1
1  2  2.0  2
2  3  3.0  3
3  4  4.0  4
0  1  NaN  1
1  2  NaN  2
2  3  NaN  3
3  4  NaN  4
```